# Field of type media with two values display inline

Tags: views, 10

I have two entities
1-is a media field (of type image) with 2 allowed values.
2-is a date field (date only) with 2 allowed values
When I uses these fields in a view (Table Format)
the media fields are always one over the other regardless of the multiple field setting checkbox 'display all values in the same row',
while the date field is either in line when display all values in same row is checked
or one over the other if unchecked.

How can I make the media fields display in the same row?

Comment: This Question may need a screenshot to be understandable.

Comment: I bet this is more of a display issue (HTML / CSS) than a config issue. "Display in the same row" means display in the same table row (tr), not necessarily display the multiple values inline (e.g. display: inline). Each table column may itself wrap to multiple lines.